# Explanation about rotating a bitmap by 90°

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I recently found [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667591/rotating-a-bitmap-90-degrees).

The accepted answer and the answer made by Rhubbarb works fine, but I don't understand how they work. And I don't want to use code that I don't understand in my project. I know what the basics bit operations are (shifts, ANDs , ORs etc..), but I don't understand how these assembly of operations end up doing what they're doing .

Thank you for looking at this question and hopefully be able to help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 64 bit integer `value` is represented as an 8-by-8 block - let's pretend we'd understand the "content" of each cell as follows:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
```

although `value` is actually stored sequentially as

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
```

We also say that shifting it to the left by four (`value << 4`) results in

```
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
```

or

```
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
```

and shifting it to the right by four (`value >> 4`) gives

```
  0  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  
  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 ...
```

Now let's take

```
uint64 reflect_vert (uint64 value)
{
    value = ((value & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull) >> 32) | ((value & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFull) << 32);
    value = ((value & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000ull) >> 16) | ((value & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFFull) << 16);
    value = ((value & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00ull) >>  8) | ((value & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FFull) <<  8);
    return value;
}
```

Here, the `0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull`-like pieces are bit masks which, in combination with the AND operation, select bits from `value`. 
Also note that `0xFF` corresponds to one byte with eight bits set, so `0xFFFFFFFF` effectively describes `4*8=32` selected bits. Since each row is `8` bits long, this corresponds to `4` rows.

Concretely, `value & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull` selects (keeps!) the upper 32 bits of `value`, i.e. the first four rows, and discards the rest, while `value & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFull` selects the lower 32 bits and discards the first. (It does not actually discard anything, but rather sets the value of those elements/positions that do not match to zero.)

The shifts operations in

```
((value & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull) >> 32)
((value & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFull) << 32)
```

then move these bits either downwards (`>> 32`) onto the location of the lower 32 bits or upwards (`<< 32`). By OR-ing them together,

```
value = ((value & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull) >> 32) | ((value & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFull) << 32);
```

you have effectively swapped them. Now since the lower 32 bits correspond to the "bottom half" of the block, we just swapped the rows like so:

```
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 \
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 |__
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 |  |
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 /  |
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 \  |
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 |__|
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 |
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 /
```

Performing the same with `0xFFFF0000FFFF0000ull` and `0x0000FFFF0000FFFFull`, using shifts of width `16` swaps two rows each with their neighbors:

```
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 \__
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 /  |
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 \__|
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 /
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 \__
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 /  |
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 \__|
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 /
```

Finally, `0xFF00FF00FF00FF00ull` and `0x00FF00FF00FF00FFull` with shifts of `8` swap every other row, resulting in

```
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 _
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 _
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 _
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 _
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

at which point the block has been successfully flipped vertically.

The `reflect_diag` method uses the same approach to swap bits selectively. The thing to note here is that `0x0100000000000000` selects the eight-highest (top row, left of the middle) bit:

```
0000 0001 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

while `0x0000000000000080` selects the eight-lowest (bottom row, right of the middle)

```
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 1000 0000
```

bit. They are exactly `49` bits apart, so shifting them by `49` swaps their location.

For another example, the pattern `0x4020100804020100` selects the bits

```
0100 0000 0010 0000 
0001 0000 0000 1000
0000 0100 0000 0010
0000 0001 0000 0000
```

whereas its counterpart `0x0080402010080402` selects

```
0000 0000 1000 0000
0100 0000 0010 0000
0001 0000 0000 1000
0000 0100 0000 0010
```

You'll notice that the distances between the bits form a pattern that allows the whole block to be shifted in such a way that they align with each other's original position.

Also note that compared to the horizontally and vertically flipped versions, this code does not overwrite the original values but composes a new output. Michiel's code does the shifting in-place and encodes the shifts in octal, so `>> 010` actually means `>> 8`, `020` is `16` and so on.

Comment: great explanation ! Thank you a lot !